# Inequality in parabolic equations

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality, parabolic-pde

**Problem:** Let $\Omega$ a smooth, bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. Let a final time $T>0$, an initial data $u_{0} \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and a source term $f \in L^{2}((0, T))$. Let $u$ the solution of
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\partial_{t} u-\Delta_{x} u=f, \text { a.e. in } \Omega \times(0, T), \\
u=0, \text { a.e. in } \delta \Omega \times(0, T), \\
u(0, x)=u_{0}(x), \text { a.e. in } \Omega .
\end{array}\right.
$$

Prove the following inequality, for $t \in[0, T]$ :
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} u(t, x)^{2} d x+\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\Omega}\left|\partial_{x} u(s, x)\right|^{2} d x d s \\
&\quad \leq \frac{e^{t}}{2}\left(\int_{\Omega} u_{0}(x)^{2} d x+\int_{0}^{T} \int_{\Omega} f(s, x) u(s, x) d x d s\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

**My attempt:**
For $u$ is smooth I have shown that we have the following energy estimate:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} u(t, x)^{2} d x+\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\Omega}\left|\partial_{x} u(s, x)\right|^{2} d x d s \\
&\quad=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} u_{0}(x)^{2} d x+\int_{0}^{t} \int_{\Omega} f(s, x) u(s, x) d x d s\ (1)
\end{aligned}
$$
By applying the Gronwall Lemma I have also proved that for a function $z \in C^{0}\left([0, T], \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$satisfying
$$
z(t) \leq a+b \int_{0}^{t} z(s) d s, \quad \forall t \in[0, T], 
$$
where $a, b \geq 0$, we have
$$
\forall t \in[0, T], \quad z(t) \leq a e^{b t}.\ (2)
$$
Now, I intend to combine (1) and (2) with z is LHS of (1), $a= \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{\Omega} u_{0}(x)^{2} d x+\int_{0}^{T} \int_{\Omega} f(s, x) u(s, x) d x d s\right)$ and $b=1$ to get what we need. However, it seems like we still have missed something to attain that. Anyone can show me what should I do to have the estimation above.